# Generate job matrix from all possible combinations of input parameters

Tags: azure-pipelines

I would like to generate jobs in Azure Pipelines using the [matrix strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#matrix), but not by explicitly listing all possible combinations.
Instead of doing:

```
matrix:
  core211:
    module: core
    scala: 2.11
  python211:
    module: python
    scala: 2.11
  libraries211:
    module: ibraries
    scala: 2.11
  core212:
    module: core
    scala: 2.12
  python212:
    module: python
    scala: 2.12
  libraries212:
    module: libraries
    scala: 2.12
```

I want to do

```
matrix:
  combinations:
    module: ["libraries", "python", "core"]
    scala: ["2.11", "2.12"]
```

to generate above matrix. 
Is this possible with Azure Pipelines?

I got this approach from [Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-matrix/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible with Azure Pipelines?

I'm afraid the answer is negative. For now, it's not a supported scenario.

About the Matrix schema in yaml please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#matrix):

```
strategy:
  matrix: { string1: { string2: string3 } }
  maxParallel: number
```

It equals to:

```
    matrix:
      string1:
        string2: string3
        .
        .
        .
      string1:
        string2: string3
        .
        .
        .
```

**According to the docs:** *For each string1 in the matrix, a copy of the job will be generated. string1 is the copy's name and will be appended to the name of the job.*

So if we want to generate 6 jobs, for now we have to list 6 "`string1`". (It means we do need to explicitly list all possible combinations...)

**In addition:**

Apart from the negative answer, I think what you want is a good idea! So I post a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/837553/save-the-time-when-configuring-the-matrix-in-vsts.html) in [DC forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html). Anyone interested in this can vote for it and track it. Hope all above makes some help :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for filing a feature request. I've upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.  By [creating a JSON at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#multi-job-configuration) using `bash`/`script`/`powershell`/`pwsh`

and consuming that in the matrix strategy:

```
jobs:
- job: generator
  steps:
  - bash: echo "##vso[task.setVariable variable=legs;isOutput=true]{'a':{'myvar':'A'}, 'b':{'myvar':'B'}}"
    name: mtrx
  # This expands to the matrix
  #   a:
  #     myvar: A
  #   b:
  #     myvar: B
- job: runner
  dependsOn: generator
  strategy:
    matrix: $[ dependencies.generator.outputs['mtrx.legs'] ]
  steps:
  - script: echo $(myvar) # echos A or B depending on which leg is running
```