# Using parameterized templates to avoid code duplicates leads to error message: 'A sequence was expected'

Tags: azure-pipelines

For our build, I want to use a stage that is triggered for every push / pull request, with a limited number of parameter combinations in the build matrix.

Another stage, which is executed nightly using a scheduled build, I want to use the full build matrix with all parameter combinations. Since Azure Pipelines [does not support a compact representation of the build matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59076036/generate-job-matrix-from-all-possible-combinations-of-input-parameters/59085614#59085614), I would at least like to put the build matrix into a separate file, so that file is at least clearly arranged.

**azure-pipelines.yml** (the main file)

```
stages:
  - stage: ci_build_on_default_pool
    jobs:
      - template: tools/azure-pipelines/azure-jobs.yml
        parameters:
          stage_name: ci_build_on_default_pool
          pool_definition:
            name: Default
          test_strategy:
            - template: tools/azure-pipelnes/ci-build-matrix.yml

  - stage: ci_build_on_azure_os_free_pool
    jobs:
      - template: tools/azure-pipelines/azure-jobs.yml
        parameters:
          stage_name: ci_build_on_azure_os_free_pool
          pool_definition:
            vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
          test_strategy:                
            - template: tools/azure-pipelnes/ci-build-matrix.yml

  # Special stage for midnight build:
  - stage: cron_build_on_azure_os_free_pool
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule')
    jobs:
      - template: tools/azure-pipelines/azure-jobs.yml
        parameters:
          stage_name: cron_build_on_azure_os_free_pool
          pool_definition:
            vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
          test_strategy:
              matrix:
                core:
                  parameter: core
                python:
                  parameter: python
                libraries:
                  parameter: libraries
```

**azure-jobs.yml** (file containing the definition of the build jobs)

```
parameters:
  pool_definition:
  stage_name:
  test_strategy: {}

jobs:
[ ... ]

- job: runOnAzure_test
  pool: ${{parameters.pool_definition}}
  container: flink-build-container
  strategy: ${{parameters.test_strategy}}
  steps:
```

**ci-build-matrix.yml** (default matrix definition shared across two stages)

```
matrix:
  core:
    parameter: core
  python:
    parameter: python
  libraries:
    parameter: libraries

[ ... ]
```

The [full source is available here](https://github.com/rmetzger/flink/tree/dbd73c42733525050f10fd8e59c738b56b757c95).

With these inputs, I'm getting the following [error](https://dev.azure.com/rmetzger/Flink/_build/results?buildId=2672&view=results):

```
/tools/azure-pipelines/azure-jobs.yml (Line: 60, Col: 13): A sequence was not expected
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I recall encountering this issue when I first started using templates. Im pretty sure it has to something to with the first step of a template has to be a task.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your response pushed me into the right direction: It seems that AZP supports 4 types of templates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#template-references
So I can not just move out any part of the pipeline into a separate template file.